# The next colour

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, color

## Challenge

Consider the rainbow as seven colours, represented by strings as `Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet`.
Your task is to create a program that receives one of these colours as input and outputs next in order rainbow colour. This includes overlapping `Violet -> Red`

## Input

A string containing one of rainbow colours.

## Output

The next in order colour of the rainbow.

## Rules

- Colour names are case sensitive. They must match the case included in this post.
- The input will always be valid. Any behavior is allowed for invalid input.
- This is code golf, so the shortest amount of bytes wins!

## Example Input and Output

```
Input -> Output
Red -> Orange
Orange -> Yellow
Yellow -> Green
Green -> Blue
Blue -> Indigo
Indigo -> Violet
Violet -> Red
```

Comment: "Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like."  Are you describing your own challenge post?  Or is this a requirement for solutions?

Comment: Do the test cases give the exact set of possible inputs? Do we have to use the same capitalization?

Comment: Are lower case colours okay?

Comment: But what happens when you reach 'gray'? ;)

Comment: @Emigna From the way OP phrased the question, I would guess that you can choose whether to do upper case, lower case, or case insensitive. `Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.`

Comment: @Enigma lower case colours are not okay

Comment: Are trailing spaces okay?

Comment: The issue I have with wrapping back to the first color is that double rainbows reverse direction rather than starting over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
k‰³d∆|ΝμHō↑≥░δ÷f‘θ⁽,WIw
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=ayV1MjAzMCVCM2QldTIyMDYlN0MldTAzOUQldTAzQkNIJXUwMTREJXUyMTkxJXUyMjY1JXUyNTkxJXUwM0I0JUY3ZiV1MjAxOCV1MDNCOCV1MjA3RCUyQ1dJdw__,inputs=Qmx1ZQ__)

Explanation:

```
...‘θ⁽,WIw  
...‘        push "red orange yellow green blue indigo violet"
    θ       split on spaces
     ⁽      uppercase the 1st letter of every item (SOGLs dictionary only has lowercase words)
      ,W    get the inputs index in the array
        I   increment
         w  and get that item in the array, wrapping if necessary
```

Answer (score 22):

## JavaScript, 68 bytes

```
s=>'RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed'.match(s+'(.[a-z]*)')[1]
```

For input `"Red"`, this function first construct an RegExp `/Red(.[a-z]*)/` to match the string `'RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed'` and then return the first capture result.

```js
f=
s=>'RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed'.match(s+'(.[a-z]*)')[1]

document.write('<table><tr><th>Input<th>Output')
for(i='Red';;){
document.write(`<tr><td>${i}<td>${i=f(i)}`);
if(i=='Red')break;
}
```

Comment: What's the result for input "Violet"? I guess you should change the text to `'RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed'` or something

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ok, added. This rule is changed by OP after answer posted.

Comment: I didn't know: I only saw the final version of the question.

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_={(Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet)x2}->{$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZaIyg1Rce/KDEvPVUnMjUnJ79cx70oNTVPxymnNFXHMy8lMz1fJywzPye1RLPCqFbXrlolvvb/f4jIv/yCksz8vOL/ugX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Now that the challenge has been changed to be cyclic the regex solution

```perl
say RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed=~/$_(.[a-z]+)/
```

isn't optimal anymore (due to the double `Red`)

Also 57 bytes:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=(Indigo,Blue,Violet,Yellow,Orange,Red,Green)[ord>>2&7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDMy8lMz1fxymnNFUnLDM/J7VEJzI1Jye/XMe/KDEvPVUnKDVFx70oNTVPMzq/KMXOzkjNPPb/f6Dov/yCksz8vOL/ugX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 79 bytes

```python
z="Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet".split()*2
dict(zip(z,z[1:])).get
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ncyxCsIwEADQvV9xdGkisWDHQh1cxElwEEQcxFziQbiEeGLMz8d/8H3AS195Rp5aq0t/QgvHfGePcMEQ4gf2GZFhF94IB7bkI5wpBpR@fKVAovRq6txi6SGqUlLV1Otmvmk9epTmYoYCxPBPPHeQMrFAMcN6Oxinim4/)

Handles `Violet -> Red`. The desired function is given anonymously in the second line.

---

**80 bytes**

```python
lambda x:"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red".split(x)[1].split()[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSikoNUXBvygxLz1VITI1Jye/XMG9KDU1T8EppzRVwTMvJTM9XyEsMz8ntUQBqFRJr7ggJ7NEo0Iz2jAWytaMNoj9n5ZfpFChkJmnQIKBMMM0rbgUCooy80oUKnTUde3UddKA5v8HAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 56 bytes

```perl6
{<Indigo Blue Violet Yellow Orange Red Green>[.ord/4%8]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2sYzLyUzPV/BKac0VSEsMz8ntUQhMjUnJ79cwb8oMS89VSEoNUXBvSg1Nc8uWi@/KEXfRNUitvZ/cWKlgpJKvIKtnUJ1moZKvGatkkJafpGCDUg5VCfUHLBmiAVQyyD22P0HAA)

Exploits the fact that bits 2-4 of the ASCII codes of each color's first letter happen to map to 0-6.

```perl6
say map (*.ord +> 2) % 8, <R O Y G B I V>
# (4 3 6 1 0 2 5)
```

Here's a nice non-competing solution that uses "purple" instead of "indigo" and "violet" (38 chars, 59 bytes):

```perl6
{''.uninames~~m/$^a.\S+.<(\S+/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wv3D/N6@D/OXL/wwf9JsIJ4FxDOBeA5IXF2vNC8zLzE3tbiuLldfJS5RLyZYW89GA0jq1/4vTqxUUFKJV7C1U6hO01CJ16xVUkjLL1KwCXJ1UfAPcvRzd1WIdPXx8Q9XcA9ydfVTcPIJdVUICA0K8HG1@w8A)

Comment: Almighty Unicode names

Comment: As interesting as this solution is, it ultimately doesn't follow the spec. Could you include a compliant version in you answer and post this as an addendum?

Comment: There is also a `%12` solution for Coconut, but of course this is neater.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>62</s> 60 bytes

-2 by Asone Tuhid.

```ruby
p"RedVioletIndigoBlueGreenYellowOrangeRed"[/.[a-z]+(?=#$_)/]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0ApKDUlLDM/J7XEMy8lMz3fKac01b0oNTUvMjUnJ7/cvygxLz0VqEYpWl8vOlG3KlZbw95WWSVeUz/2/3@g@L/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5AA)

Regex approach looks promising for Ruby too. However, I arrived at a shorter solution using a lookahead and directly printing the match, rather than playing with capturing groups. The list of colors is in reverse direction since lookahead is 1 byte cheaper than lookbehind.

Comment: very nice, [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0ApKDUlLDM/J7XEMy8lMz3fKac01b0oNTUvMjUnJ7/cvygxLz0VqEYpWl8vOlG3KlZbw95WWSVeUz/2/3@g@L/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5AA) (`/#$_/` interpolates)

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 87 bytes

```
func[c][print first find/tail[Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red]to-word c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCsMwDEDRPacQ3kP3jl1Kp0CHQjEegi0Hg5CK6pDjO468SB8hnmJqb0w@TPne8s7Rx@B/WrhCLvq/JqdbXQv5/gaLrrwhfJFIDngqIsODdoQXp7IJfIoQVuivocp8iCaIoWVw/eKmvgdgORBLg6wuzGKAlgN17QQ)

Comment: No idea what this language is, whether or how your code works, or whether it's golfed at all, but have a +1 just for using a language called "Red" for this challenge.

Comment: @ msh210 It's closely related to Rebol ( Relative Expression-Based Object Language). The language represents code, data and metadata in the same manner - with blocks denoted by []. The current Red distribution is only 1.1 MB and includes a console/interpeter, as well as compiler that can cross-complie to different platforms.
My code is golfed in the sence that I tried different solutions and removed all the spaces I can. The bad thing is that the space is the delimiter almost everywhere. All math expressions need to have spaces on both sides of the operators like a: b + c (a=b+c).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 30 bytes

```
“†¾›ÈŠÛˆ¨‡—ëßigo°Íolet“#™DIk>è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOcRw0LDu171LDrcMfRBYdnn247tOJRw8JHDVMOrz48PzM9/9CGw735OaklQJXKj1oWuXhm2x1e8f9/WCZIEAA)

**Explanation**

```
“†¾›ÈŠÛˆ¨‡—ëßigo°Íolet“          # push a string of colours
                       #         # split on spaces
                        ™        # title-case each
                         D       # duplicate
                          Ik     # get the index of the input
                            >    # increment
                             è   # get the element at that index
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>80 71</s> 75 bytes

<sup>Thanks to Laikoni for shortening 9 bytes!</sup>

```hs
g x=snd(span(/=x)$words"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red")!!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBasMwEETv/orR0oN9KvkAXXIJISGGBgq9xaCNbaJIwZKJ@/WuHLki0m00b5eZ7Rp3Y63nucUknVGlezSm/JRT9fG0g3L0xQr10JiW8RNA@8RuYDbY6pGxN6pvLb57q9kjoFQJsZknXFxnR622fMEvJB6jP/vhaFD2V0yQMvz6Lmyh@kBg7Rh0sh71QQhBVVHcm96EOWULhNdiiUHvWylmon9/lRkS8yZklRny6pKIqDJgqZn8l8jseIAErDJD4nESssoMWcoV8x8)

---

Another solution, slightly more idiomatic, but I could not get it shorter:

```hs
data R=Red|Orange|Yellow|Green|Blue|Indigo|Violet deriving(Enum,Read,Eq)
succ.read
```

It needs to derive `Read` because of the requirement that the input is a string and at least `Eq` or `Show` in order to either test for equality or show the result.

Comment: 71 bytes with `span`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBCsIwEETv/YrJ4qE9iR@QixcRxYKC4M1C1rYYk9KkWL@@RluL2dvsvCwzqQp3Z62HoUQvnVGpawqTLmWfLZ62VY6OrJC3hSkZlwDaJzYts8Fad4ytUXVpca6tZk@ZEKuhx9VVttNqzVe8INF0/uTbvUFa39BDyrD1VbhA@Y7A2jHoYD3ynRCCsiR5FLUJ75RNEKbEJwL9X6UxD/38SUbImHVGJhkh3x4zMaoI@FSc/a@I7LH8DEwyQqaPSYY3 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni Wow, that's cool, thanks! I forgot about `span`...

Comment: OP clarified that `Violet` should wrap around to `Red`, so you need to add `Red` again to the end of the string.

Comment: I like the idea of the second one a lot! However `succ Violet` won't work for `Enum`s don't wrap around :(

Comment: @BMO Exactly. When I made that version I wasn't aware of the wrap-around requirement.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 77 bytes

```java
s->"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red".split(s)[1].split(" ")[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc/BaoQwEAbgu0/xExC0aKDXpvXQQ0sPpVChUJY9pBptbEzEjFuWss9u1biHMBlmMt@kkyeZd/XPrPvBjYRuyflE2vBmshVpZ/mNiCojvcer1BZ/ETBMX0ZX8CRpCSena/RLLSlp1LY9HCHH1qdbK/C0z7kP1SyEAg0eZp8X7F3VeBulbRU@lTHuF8@jUhaPZlJ4sbVuHT60M4qwtDLuB6Mp8enh9rjfGdiazWLzGjfui4CUJ9xhJUQgRCDERoiVEIEQgRCl6xV9L4@vEBMsvX4FKM@eVM/dRHxYCGoSFnvkBWIfW5ZtYoaGy2Ew52TN0jSsdYnWc5n/AQ)

### Credits

- -10 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
- -1 byte thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx)

Comment: **78 bytes**: [`s->"RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed".split(s)[1].split("(?=[A-Z])")[0]`](https://tinyurl.com/ycmbqedl)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That some nice regex fu that you've got!

Comment: I remembered when I once was looking for a split which keeps delimiters as separated items that the answer I found also contained options to keep the delimiter concatted as either leading or trailing part, and figured it would be useful here. :) [Here is that answer including the look-ahead / look-behind for the other two options mentioned.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/1682559)

Comment: Save a byte: `s->"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red".split(s)[1].split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 85 bytes

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(CODE(A1),12),"green","indigo","yellow",,,"orange","blue",,"violet","red")
```

Uses lowercase names.

Same approach, with Uppercase letters 86 bytes:

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(CODE(A1),12),"Violet","Red",,,"Green","Indigo","Yellow",,,"Orange","Blue")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <strike>59</strike> <strike>56</strike> <strike>53</strike> 52 Bytes

-1 byte thanks to tsh

```
2IYellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red Orange <Esc>*wywVp
```

Comment: 2IYellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red Orange <Esc>*wywVp

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>65</s> 58 bytes

```
$
(.[a-z]+)
L$:`RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F@FS0MvOlG3KlZbk8tHxSohKDXFvygxLz01MjUnJ7/cvSg1Nc8ppzTVMy8lMz0/LDM/J7UEqIZLxfD/fxANUcwFUc0FVs4FUs8F0cAF0QEA)

#### Explanation

```
$
(.[a-z]+)
```

We start by appending `(.[a-z]+)` to the input, thereby turning it into a regex which matches the input colour, immediately followed by exactly one more colour (capturing the latter).

```
L$:`RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed
$1
```

Now the `:` swaps the stage's input with its own regex. So the previous result becomes the regex and it's matched against the list of colours. The (single) match gets replaced with its first capturing group (i.e. the next colour in the cycle) and returned. Output at the end of the program happens automatically.

Comment: Here is [another 65-byte alternative](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F@FSycoNcW/KDEvPTUyNScnv9y9KDU1zymnNNUzLyUzPT8sMz8ntQSohktDT1tTTyvGUEMvOlG3KhbE4VIx@v8fJAcxgAtiAhfYCC6QGVwQQ7ggpgAA).

Comment: Yeah, I removed my comment after seeing Kevin's solution. Having to set up `\1` and jumping to the target wastes many bytes ::-)

Comment: @TonHospel found something. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks to your and Ton's pushing for a no-delimiter solution, I ended up finding a 58-byter. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇôF┘≡▓ƒ◄╙>┘☼░⌂╪B<U[ÇQ╒eöΣQ╔÷n
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=809346d9f0b29f11d33ed90fb07fd8423c555b8051d56594e451c9f66e&i=Red%0AOrange%0AYellow%0AViolet&a=1&m=2)

This uses the ring translation instruction.  It replaces each element in an array with the following one from the "decoder ring".  Usually, it's used to do character replacement in a string, but it can be used on an entire string too, if it's wrapped in a singleton array.

Here's the unpacked, ungolfed, commented ascii representation of the same program.

```
]   wrap input in singleton array
`5^bZ_9G*h]h%oM~X9e-0ZQJkb2`    compressed string literal with color names
:.j title case and split on spaces
:t  do ring translation
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=]%09wrap+input+in+singleton+array%0A%605%5EbZ_9G*h]h%25oM%7EX9e-0ZQJkb2%60%09compressed+string+literal+with+color+names%0A%3A.j%09title+case+and+split+on+spaces%0A%3At%09do+ring+translation&i=Red%0AOrange%0AYellow%0AViolet&a=1&m=2)

Comment: ok... I love these languages =)

Comment: Fails for Violet -> Red

Comment: @WeijunZhou:  That test case was added *after* this submission.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: I fixed that test case and shaved a byte.

Comment: Not sure why, but this appears to fail on tio.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: It seems to be an inconsistency between the C# and JS implementations of stax.  I'll add a test case and normalize the behavior for the next release.

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 79 bytes

```
s->"# Violet Red # # Green Indigo Yellow # # Orange Blue".split()[ord(s[0])%12]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzv1jXTklZISwzPye1RCEoNUVBGQjdi1JT8xQ881Iy0/MVIlNzcvLLweL@RYl56akKTjmlqUp6xQU5mSUamtH5RSkaxdEGsZqqhkax/9PyixQqFDLzFJRAhkE1QI2AGAvSDTMbYi/cLCsuhYKizLwSjQoddV07dZ00jQpNzf8A)

Comment: Don't know Coconut.  But think you should be able to cut 2 bytes by using lowercase letters, as this reduces the max modulo value: `s->"# green indigo yellow # # orange blue # violet red".split()[ord(s[0])%12]`

Comment: @Wernisch Thanks for the suggestion. Though I'll wait until OP has responded whether lowercase letters are acceptable before updating.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>67 64</strike> 62 bytes

-2 bytes thank to FrownyFrog

```
>:&.((cut'Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red')i.<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7azU9DQ0kktL1INSUxT8ixLz0lMVIlNzcvLLFdyLUlPzFJxySlMVPPNSMtPzFcIy83NSSxSAStU1M/VsNP9rcilwpSZn5CukKYAMUIdzwHoRXIhGda7/AA)

Comment: `&.` actually works for this. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8HOSk1PQyO5tEQ9KDVFwb8oMS89VSEyNScnv1zBvSg1NU/BKac0VcEzLyUzPV8hLDM/J7VEAahUXTNTz0bzf2pyRr5CmgJIszoXjAPWh@BCNKn/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 28 bytes

```
S!o→€⁰w¨ṙ}ΘΞĠ«ẇ₇G²€ḃλBżḃIÿö⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUkAtv9odXNr//9TIW/ihpLigqzigbB3wqjhuZl9zpjOnsSgwqvhuofigodHwrLigqzhuIPOu0LFvOG4g0nDv8O24oyJ////VmlvbGV0)

Maybe there are better options for managing the arguments, but this is the best I could find

#### Explanation

```
S!o→€⁰w¨ṙ}ΘΞĠ«ẇ₇G²€ḃλBżḃIÿö⌉
       ¨ṙ}ΘΞĠ«ẇ₇G²€ḃλBżḃIÿö⌉    Compressed string with all the colors
                                "Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet"
      w                         Split on spaces
S                               Pass the list to both the following functions:
    €⁰                          1) Find the index of the input in the list
  o→                                  and increase it by one
 !                              2) Get the element of the list at the
                                   resulting position (indexing is cyclical)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>109</s> 93 bytes

```r
function(x){y=c("Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet");y[match(x,y)%%7+1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO60jZZQykoNUVJR8m/KDEvPRXIiEzNyckvBzLci1JT84C0U04pSNwzLyUzPR/ICMvMz0ktUdK0rozOTSxJztCo0KnUVFU11zaMrf2fBjFPkwvIgBoJZkNNBbMhBoOZYLPBLKjxYDbMhv8A)

-16 thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) for the use of `match` advice

Comment: welcome to PPCG! this is a nice first answer. I think `match(y,x)%%7+1` is shorter for indexing than your `if` statement. Additionally, the builtin `colors()` contains a lot of color names, if you find the indices :)

Comment: oops, looks like `colors()` doesn't contain `indigo`! Ah well, still, +1!

Comment: thanks! `match` is better here

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQlOj0jZZQykoNUVJR8m/KDEvPRXIiEzNyckvBzLci1JT84C0U04pSNwzLyUzPR/ICMvMz0ktUdLUjM5NLEnO0KjQqdRUVTXXNoz9nwYxTZMLyIAaCGZDzQSzIcaCmWCTwSyo4WA2zPz/AA)

Comment: and yeah I first tried to use `colors()` :/

Comment: how!? I copied that from tio, let me see again

Comment: aha, cool! I just got it :D

Comment: @Giuseppe [grep is your friend](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQlOj0jZZQykoNUVJR8m/KDEvPRXIiEzNyckvBzLci1JT84C0U04pSNwzLyUzPR/ICMvMz0ktUdLUjE4vSi3QqNCp1FRVNdc2jP2fBjFMkwvIgJoHZkONBLMhpoKZYIPBLKjZYDbM@P8A)

Answer (score 1):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language, <s>79</s> 74 bytes

```
@Left(@Right("Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red ";a+" ");" ")
```

Previous version for 79:

```
R:=@Explode("Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Red");R[@Member(a;R)+1]
```

Takes input from an editable text field called `a`.

There is no TIO for formula language so here's a couple of screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 67 characters

```
*=@subst{*\?<J>=\?\$2\;\?=;RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ echo -n Yellow | gema '*=@subst{*\?<J>=\?\$2\;\?=;RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed}'
Green

bash-4.4$ echo -n Violet | gema '*=@subst{*\?<J>=\?\$2\;\?=;RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed}'
Red
```

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 59 characters

```
R=Orange
O=Yellow
Y=Green
G=Blue
B=Indigo
I=Violet
V=Red
*=
```

Boring one. Dumbest approach ever, but quite short.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema 'R=Orange;O=Yellow;Y=Green;G=Blue;B=Indigo;I=Violet;V=Red;*=' <<< 'Yellow'
Green

bash-4.4$ gema 'R=Orange;O=Yellow;Y=Green;G=Blue;B=Indigo;I=Violet;V=Red;*=' <<< 'Violet'
Red
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```ruby
a=%w{Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet};p a[-~(a.index$_)%7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9FWtbw6KDVFwb8oMS89VSEyNScnv1zBvSg1NU/BKac0VcEzLyUzPV8hLDM/J7Wk1rpAITFat04jUS8zLyW1QiVeU9U89v9/iOy//IKSzPy84v@6eQA)

Comment: Why the `i&&` thing? No need to check for `nil`, as “Ignore any errors if this is not a colour.”

Comment: @manatwork I understood it as "catch and ignore any errors" but alright.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 97 bytes

```
@set s=Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red
@call set s=%%s:*%1 =%%
@echo %s: =&rem %
```

Explanation: The `call` on the second line has the effect of substituting the parameter into the command and evaluating it, turning it into e.g. `set s=%s:Red =%`, which deletes the prefix of the string that includes the parameter. The substitution on the third line then replaces all the spaces with statement separators and comments. This works because string substitution happens before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 76 bytes

```julia
f(s)=match(Regex("$s(.[a-z]*)"),"RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoViolet"^2)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNY0zY3sSQ5QyMoNT21QkNJpVhDLzpRtypWS1NJU0cpKDXFvygxLz01MjUnJ7/cvSg1Nc8ppzTVMy8lMz0/LDM/J7VEKc5IM9ow9v9/AA)

This handles the Violet->Red by recycling the string with the power `^` operator.

Here's a slightly longer solution without regexes:

```julia
g(s,l=split("Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet"," "))=l[(findin(l,[s])[1])%7+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 74 bytes

```powershell
(-split("Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet "*2-split$args)[1])[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0O3uCAns0RDKSg1RcG/KDEvPVUhEiiTX67gXpSamqfglFOaquCZl5KZnq8Qlpmfk1qioKRlBNGlkliUXqwZbRirGW0Q@///f3WIAnUA)

Takes the string `"Red ... Violet "` and string-multiplies it out by two to properly handle the `Violet -> Red` test case. We then `-split` that string on input `$args` to give us an array of two strings. We take the second string thereof `[1]`, then `-split` that on whitespace to give us an array of strings and take the first `[0]`.

For example, for input `"Yellow"`, the first step will result in `@("Red Orange ", " Green Blue Indigo ... Indigo Violet ")`. We take the second one of that, split it on whitespace (which removes the whitespace), resulting in `@("Green", "Blue", ... "Violet")`, so taking the `[0]` one thereof results in the proper next string.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 92 bytes

```
$a=" Red   OrangeYellowGreen Blue  IndigoVioletRed";echo substr($a,strpos($a,$argv[1])+6,6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsIwEEB/5SgZLNahSxetBRdxKjgIIlKiOZJAuAtJqn/vWXF6b3i86KLIblC6r@CMBgDGpMniFUPg9zEhEhzCjAAnMt7yxXPAspTVFp@OIc@PXNJK6WZB5PwzpZN93dp7ve6arh72IvLffTgWz5RlYyA7TmXiiDQVbXumLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 73 bytes

```
x->"RedOrangeYellow Green  BlueIndigoVioletRed".substringAfter(x).take(6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc7BCsIwDAbg@54iFA8tdDt6GDhQEPEkKAgeq6azWFvpMh2MPfvsVn8I5PAnfE9P1rhRtw5eyjj@UUGFGuI0JZwoGFcL6DOIYUe8y0NQrkZ5QWv9V@4CopMb26Lcu7upvTwbb5FY0bytIc4kE4X2Yatuj/@XKe/4lqzjbGEI8goWveaGxMDEXBmyIcs@yoIueVf@EXmVllU/dnk1WRIlSWCWAEyUJEmQWIuW9trMt2tNGHgnClJP5EsxDuMP)

Taking advantage of the fact that many colors are 6 characters, the ones that are not are prefixed with spaces to make them 6 characters long.   Hopefully it's acceptable that some of the colors are outputted with spaces before them.
e.g. Red is `"   Red"`, Blue is `"  Blue"`

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>94</s> 84 bytes

```
C$="Red   OrangeYellowGreen Blue  IndigoViolet
INPUT I$?MID$(C$*2,INSTR(C$,I$)+6,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash + GNU Utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 63

```bash
grep -Po $1\\K.[a-z]+<<<RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed
```

<strike>The list of colours is reversed so that a regex lookahead may be used.  The lookahead boilerplate is one byte shorter than the lookbehind boilerplate.</strike>  Of course we can do better the PCRE `\K`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwEAbg3af4h24SwdlMLiIOioNQrEM0ZwyEnFxbCr78Wb3947uH/qVPFjy48CjIFWeKOEqoidBSKTxhJ0QV2zIS9jXmxLhkLjRsEHkBoKcBzqGxQ5PQG@7EaNZdd1hdg/vclt77ObbX2v/6S@20cjYauZKq0S8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Shaggy*

```
`R‚sOÎÁƒYÁMwsGÎ9sBluƒI˜igosVio¤t`qs
g1+UbNg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PyHoUFOx/@G@w42HmiMPN/qWF7sf7rMsdsopPdTseWhGZnp@cVhm/qElJQmFxVzphtqhSX7p//8rAcVyUkuUAA)

Comment: [43 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YFKCc0/OwYNZwU13c0fOOXNCbHWDSZhpZ29zVmlvpHRgcXMKZzErVWJOZw==&input=IlZpb2xldCI=)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! I forgot about `N`

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

**Solution:**

```
.[!;2 8#($)`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange]
```

**Examples:**

```
q).[!;2 8#($)`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange]"Red"
"Violet"
q).[!;2 8#($)`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange]"Orange"
"Red"
q).[!;2 8#($)`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange]"Blue"
"Green"
```

**Explanation:**

Create a dictionary of colour => next colour, the input is the key to the dictionary:

```
.[!;2 8#($)`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange] / the solution
.[ ;                                                  ] / apply multiple args to function
           `Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange  / list of colours
         ($)                                            / convert to strings
    2 8#                                                / reshape into 2x8 grid
  !                                                     / create dictionary
```

**Bonus:**

It's **53 bytes** in K4:

```
.[!;2 8#$`Red`Violet`Indigo`Blue`Green`Yellow`Orange]
```

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 72 bytes

```
s/$/%RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoVioletRed/;s/(.+)%.*\1(.[a-z]+).*/\2/
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9FXzUoNcW/KDEvPTUyNScnv9y9KDU1zymnNNUzLyUzPT8sMz8ntQSoRt@6WF9DT1tTVU8rxlBDLzpRtypWW1NPSz/GSP//f6ACLogpXBBjuMDmcIEM4oKYxAUx6l9@QUlmfl7xf90iAA)

**Example 1:**

Input:

```
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet
```

Output:

```
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet
Red
```

**Example 2:**

Input:

```
Indigo
Yellow
Red
Red
Blue
Green
Orange
Violet
Green
Green
Green
Blue
Blue
Violet
```

Output:

```
Violet
Green
Orange
Orange
Indigo
Blue
Yellow
Red
Blue
Blue
Blue
Indigo
Indigo
Red
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide a link to an online interpreter, such as [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#) where we can test this solution?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: Hi, thank you very much for the welcome and the website recommendation! I've updated my answer with a link to the page where you can test the code online.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 81 bytes

```
[ qw{ Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet } [ index 1 + 7 mod ] keep nth ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xC8IwEIX3/oq3OzkJurmULgqKgpQOoTnbYHpp05QKpb89xjS33IN338e9Re2M9Y97ccmPGGmYiGsa0QnX4kOWSWOYoQxOWTbMS4YwN5JxX63ghmJ8kdZmjjG3RBzTWU9bW7BUjYnxqYwml62@DN7lr0qapNjwiCYsIVhRQrGkL/bY4YDOSFThR@rB4dnKd6IPJ71V7EJBom79Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 74 bytes

```
func[c][prin select[Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red]load c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BCgIxEAS/0u/w6EU8CR4ECXMIk84aGDMy7uLzYxZf4Lm6mgqWcWVBElT3w6hb16SSXtE63jTqmnZ@idwX4k4z/@AUZMfRNuLcS1sct@bGFXMq5rlAZVQPZn1A3Tzwx4ukmTJz4vlzZXwB)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 66 bytes

```
↑(c⍳⊂⎕)⌽c←'Red' 'Orange' 'Yellow' 'Green' 'Blue' 'Indigo' 'Violet'
```

Prompts for screen input of colour as a string.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>89</s> 87 bytes

```
def f(c):a="red orange yellow green blue indigo violet".split();print a[-~a.index(c)%7]
```

**Test cases:**

`f("red")` -> orange

`f("orange")` -> yellow

`f("yellow")` -> green

`f("green")` -> blue

`f("blue")` -> indigo

`f("indigo")` -> violet

`f("violet")` -> red

`f("notAColour")` -> Error

Comment: No, it's correct! I said to assume the input _is_ a colour, so you don't have to implement other things

Comment: I think your modulus needs to be 7, not 6.  Also, there are a few things you can do to get down to 81. https://tio.run/##Rc6xCsIwEMbxufcUR0BooRZ0EQodxMnJB1CRtL22gZiEmFi7@OoxtaDj/e8bfmZyg1bb0FWXIPm9bjk2Oa@YpRa15aonnEhKPWJviRTW0hMK1Ype41NoSY4VDyOFS7OSn9dvXsQnvdImW@2uYRyEJNyUkHDbY4WWjzehjI9rSIwVyiE7zneJLMe4@dWTd3OOtUtj/89ZiDRYaLDQ4EuDmQYLDRYaKO32By21tx8

Comment: @lolad thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @recursive I originally missed out orange from the string, and must have forgotten to change it, thanks :)

Comment: OP specified that colors need to be uppercase.

Comment: @Laikoni `Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.` I think that means that the colours can be any case, as long at it is specified in the answer

Comment: They wrote `lower case colours are not okay` [in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/159762/the-next-colour/159801?noredirect=1#comment387799_159762).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc) preprocessor macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 74

Score is 74 bytes passed to the compiler.

Same idea as [@nwellnhof's Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159807/11259).

```c
-Df(c)=printf("%.6s","IndigoBlue  VioletYellowOrangeRed   Green"+*c/4%8*6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@//9/bmJmnoYmVzUXZ0FRZl5JmoZSUGqKgq6dgpKmNZcCEEBEQDzOgtKSYg0lCBOq2L8oMS89FU09RBCXlsjUnJz8cjQtEEFcWtyLUlPz0HSAxXBpcMopRXcUSAiXcs@8lMz0fDQNEEFcWsIy83NSS9C0QATRtNT@/5eclpOYXvxf1yVNI1nTFmaEqp5ZsZIO1B6wixUgBkACAxKKoNhQUIB4VlsrWd9E1ULLTBMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 88 bytes

```c
f(char*s){printf("%.6s",(strstr("red   violetindigoblue  green yelloworangered",s)+6));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFPCwIhEMXP7acYjED7d@xSdOgSnYIOQcfNdV3BNHS3iGU/@@ZqQQmCBx3e783Mky44pf1YKCqbgm1sXQi9rLbZT8UIxV2pLzGtcjO1pL27Ul1iNFmuLJpjJ3EHI8MKAHgILVktVCG4vsqGAXDDmIIXk1I/tckVZ06J5pbMVoSsu96ZwS0XChNos9HX/OTcFltAZJ05Vyi9//Aa3ZvaYhSuH/HR20b60CuFXPw8ERKGTCF7v8g/4ZdLAbth/3/9EElKfvChRUBIMoWcfdoREr4gQrKufwM)

Comment: 84 bytes `f(int*s){write(1,strstr("red   violetindigoblue  green yelloworangered   ",s)+6,6);}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <strike>121</strike> 113 bytes

```
let s=readLine()!;let i=["Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet"];print(i[(i.index(of:s)!+1)%7])
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/DSR62109)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
c='Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet'.split()
f=lambda x:c[(c.index(x)+1)%7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcGxCsIwEADQvV9xiyTBWhAHoVAHF3ESHAQRh5hc24PzEmLE@PXR9@I3z0E2tbpBndHDKVmZEK7IHD5wSIgCe34jHMXTFOBCgTGr7hWZsjbNOLB9PryF0rubdh2Jx6KLWa7NYnuvY0hAQAKub@AvJpKsqVWrnWpHTcbUHw)

Comment: you can golf this by reversing the order of the colours, and using index-1 instead of (index+1)%7

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 84 bytes

TextWords version (84 Bytes but slow)

```
#/.Thread[#->RotateLeft@#&[TextWords@"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet"]]&
```

StringSplit (86 Bytes)

```
#/.Thread[#->RotateLeft@#&[StringSplit@"Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet"]]&
```

Built-in color names called by number, also 86 Bytes:

```
#/.Thread[#->RotateLeft@#&[ColorData["HTML","Range"][[1,{114,100,139,52,10,57,135}]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCgIhFAB/RVzYU7VfUEiXCIKN3QhCPDzy6QquhrzoEH27udlp5jIzA004A7k7ZLPNTbe5TAlBy2a9GyIB4QkNiaaVIyUX7PjwjgQfULM@QbDIbuh9fLFDQgxs75/IjkE7G9nVRY/ElWrzuaQkTSfeS8lXvLZFal3k1xcuh4L6KPK/fFT@Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 89 bytes

```
c="Red   OrangeYellowGreen Blue  IndigoVioletRed"r=c:find(io.read())+6print(c:sub(r,r+5))
```

Outputs some trailing spaces.
Example:

```
input: Yellow
output: Green 
space here:  ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/2VYpKDVFQUHBvygxLz01MjUnJ7/cvSg1NU/BKac0VUHBMy8lMz0/LDM/J7UEqFKpyDbZKi0zL0UjM1@vKDUxRUNTU9usoCgzr0Qj2aq4NEmjSKdI21RT8/9/iB4A)

## Lua, 102 bytes

```
c="Red   OrangeYellowGreen Blue  IndigoVioletRed"r=c:find(io.read())+6print(c:sub(r,r+5):match("%a+"))
```

Doesn't output any trailing spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCgIxDADQXwkFIaHipkPhFhdxEhwOHGMbz0JNJbbc51fB/fFK5zHi5K6SAOBirIvcpJS6nkxE4Vi6AJw15aXOuRZpP@lsiuGRNWGuOxNOSOQPb8vaMIZPv6Ntze8pvLjFJ7oNe0c0xj/4Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 98 bytes

```
puts [lindex [set L {Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet}] [expr ([lsearch $L $argv]+1)%7]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwxCgIxEAXQq/xiBcXKyt5GhAXBQpCQImw@MTAkyySrC@LZR98BXp/EbF56g5NcIle4xo4RnxsjrhpKIh4UqW@clSw4yUJcSsyp4p6rsH89HNdZsXXSGHR6YhgxBE0vvz/sNkfvzez//QA)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 98 bytes

```
puts [lindex [set L {Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Red}] [expr [lsearch $L $argv]+1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCgIxEAXQq/xiOyuvYCPCgmAhSEgRNp8YGJJlktUF8exjwP7x@iJm69YbnOQSucM1dsz43Bhx1VAS8aBIfeOsZMFJNuJSYk4V91xl6EG/Ho77qqNpDLo8Mc2YgqaXPxy9N7O//QE)